# why the or condition is not taken into account

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query

```
SELECT url
FROM 
table_repo3
WHERE
(url LIKE '%auto%'
OR url LIKE '%automobile%' 
OR url LIKE '%voiture%'
OR url LIKE '%bagnole%'
OR url LIKE '%vehicule%'
OR url LIKE '%berline%'
OR zpages LIKE '%auto%'
OR zpages LIKE '%automobile%' 
OR zpages LIKE '%voiture%'
OR zpages LIKE '%bagnole%'
OR zpages LIKE '%vehicule%'
OR zpages LIKE '%berline%')
OR url like '%google%';
```

It returns me ,every rows with `google` and `yahoo` or other URL's.

If I'm using a `AND` instead of the last `OR`, I have **no results**.

To be able to apply the condition with google, I did the following

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE toto 
SELECT *
FROM 
table_repo3
WHERE
(url LIKE '%auto%'
OR url LIKE '%automobile%' 
OR url LIKE '%voiture%'
OR url LIKE '%bagnole%'
OR url LIKE '%vehicule%'
OR url LIKE '%berline%'
OR zpages LIKE '%auto%'
OR zpages LIKE '%automobile%' 
OR zpages LIKE '%voiture%'
OR zpages LIKE '%bagnole%'
OR zpages LIKE '%vehicule%'
OR zpages LIKE '%berline%')
;
```

Then

```
SELECT url FROM temporary_table WHERE url LIKE '%google%';
```

This solution works but it is tedious and long.

Is there anything easier I can do?

TIA as always.

Comment: "Instead of retrieving only the google url I want, I have every url I can think of", what does it means?, it returns every row in your table?

Comment: Hi Lamak, I have every rows. Yes.

Comment: And are you sure that the rows that you get shouldn't be there?, I mean, they aren't like `'%auto%'` and every other condition that you have there?

Comment: If you don't want to return non "google" urls, you need to remove all those other `or url like` statements... Just use `select url from table_repo3 where url like '%google%' and (zpages like '%auto%' or zpages like '%voiture%')`...

Comment: If I understand what you want correctly, you want `AND url like '%google%'` instead of `OR`

Comment: It should not, at least the way I see it and if I'm adding the `OR url LIKE '%google%'`

Comment: Hi André, that's the thing: When putting an `AND`, the query retrieves me nothing.

Comment: Maybe you could try explaining what you want to achieve (in prose). What conditions should the urls that are returned match? Maybe add some examples.

Comment: `(a OR b OR c) OR d` is the same as `a OR b OR c OR d` the parenthesis aren't relevant in this case.

Comment: I want to have all the URL that has the condition within the bracket. And I also want to have the results within the bracket search match google.

Comment: Hi Horse, why it is not giving me the same results then?

Comment: Than the `AND` solution is the correct one. Must be another problem with your conditions...

Comment: @André, does it feel clearer?

Comment: @AndyK the results should be the same as if you use `AND url like '%google%'` at the end of your first query

Comment: That's not the case ... -_-

Comment: It's what I thought you meant and it doesn't change my answer, which is confirmed by Lamak.

Comment: @AndyK Are you absolutely completely sure that you aren't doing **any** other filters whatsoever?

Comment: nope, Lamak. David's answer is working fine for my first example. I'm trying on the second.

Comment: @AndyK so, if you do: `WHERE url LIKE '%google%'  AND (....)` it works, but if you do: `WHERE (....) AND url LIKE '%google%' ` it doesn't??

Comment: Indeed, Lamak. It is weird but it is how it is.

Comment: @AndyK No, there is no way that you are correct. You are doing somethind different than what Lamak said in the comments. You have probably removed the pernetheses in one of the queries.

Comment: @AndyK it's simply impossible...

Comment: ok everyone. I was very puzzled so I did a test and indeed, it worked with the bracket. Not sure why. I probably messed it up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_repo3
 WHERE url LIKE '%google%'
   AND ( url LIKE '%auto%'
      OR url LIKE '%automobile%' 
      OR url LIKE '%voiture%'
      OR url LIKE '%bagnole%'
      OR url LIKE '%vehicule%'
      OR url LIKE '%berline%'
      OR zpages LIKE '%auto%'
      OR zpages LIKE '%automobile%' 
      OR zpages LIKE '%voiture%'
      OR zpages LIKE '%bagnole%'
      OR zpages LIKE '%vehicule%'
      OR zpages LIKE '%berline%' );
```

But that is really not a good way of doing this. You might use a regular expression instead, but even that probably wouldn't speed things up (`LIKE`s with leading wildcards generally won't use indexes):

```
SELECT * FROM table_repo3
 WHERE url LIKE '%google%'
   AND ( url ~ '(auto)?mobile|voiture|bagnole|vehicule|berline'
      OR zpages ~ '(auto)?mobile|voiture|bagnole|vehicule|berline' );
```

Comment: Hi David, mmhhh I have to try but your answer sounds smart. Let me have a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it simply using `SIMILAR TO` in `Postgres` for multiple `Like` checking, Try this way.

```
SELECT url
  FROM 
table_repo3
  WHERE
url SIMILAR TO '%(auto|automobile|voiture|bagnole|vehicule|berline|google)%'
  OR 
zpages SIMILAR TO'%(auto|automobile|voiture|bagnole|vehicule|berline)%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding the Google OR condition AFTER the ), what SQL does is look at the first condition, see that there are matches and return them, then look at the second condition, see that there are also matches and return them.

With an AND, both conditions have to be satisfied for SQL to return something..

If it's still unclear, you should do some research on OR and AND conditions..

Comment: Hi Minh, alas no. As I said, with the `AND` , it returns me nothing.

Comment: @AndyK then post some sample data and the **exact** query that you are using because it doesn't make any sense

Comment: @AndyK, possibly because there's no url like this 'google.com/auto' ? If yes, then probably I need to delete my answer before people start downvoting it, haha..